# Why does xCode cannot build my flutter app with 'sqflite' not found error

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm trying to build my Flutter app for iOS using xCode and got error:

```
.../ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:10:9: Module 'sqflite' not found
```

When I'm trying to build application with flutter with command

```
flutter build ios
```

I don't have any problem. Application build successfully.

I tried to delete Pod directory in ios folder and then install pods from scratch

```
flutter pub get
pod install
```

How to fix this problem with xCode?

Comment: Do flutter clean first 
and then pod install

Comment: I did that action too

Answer (score 3):

XCode gives this type of Error like `Module 'something' not found`, when sometimes the problem is somewhere else.
So, what I did is after running `flutter build ios` command, I didn't try to run it in XCode. Because it was giving these errors.

So, I archived the app and tried to publish in App Store Connect. Then I found the real issue/bug on my code.

App store doesn't support transparent logo or app icon. This was the bug in my case.
So you can try to archive and publish to app store connect. It may show you the real reason.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I publish my app in AppStore without Project -> Archive? Is there any way to publish after I did `flutter build ios`. What I have to do after that?

Comment: Select `Product > Destination > Any iOS Device.` Then `Product > Archive`. For more  [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios)

Comment: But my build is broking on this stage: `Product > Archive`

Answer (score 0):

Change your target Destination to > Any iOS Device

This work for me

Answer (score 0):

"I found the solution,
In the existing project, once you guys add sqflite dependencies

Profile file in IOS folder will not generate code
we need to remove Podfile in ios
`rm ios/Podfile`
and run the project again, it works for me."

Credit:thanks to [viroth-geek](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/issues/487#issuecomment-666041806)